# Xtext, error on each space if it is in inverted comma's

Tags: xtext

I am working with xtext to make a grammar. Currently i have a code like this :

```
Model:  (commands+=Commands)*;

Commands:   
    SetCommand|CommentCommand|WhileCommand|OutputCommand
   |SelectCommand|OptionCommand|InsertAfterCommand|AdaptCommand;  

OptionCommand:  
    '#option' EXPRESSION((EXPRESSION)|(WS)|(InsertAfterCommand)|('='))* '#endoption'  ;       

terminal EXPRESSION:   
    ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'-'|'@'
    |'.'|'?'|'\''|':'|'\"'|'>'
    |'<'|'/'|'_'|';'|'('|')'
    |'&'|'!'|'#'|'*'|'+'|'['|']'|'{'|'}')
    ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'-'|'@'
    |'.'|'?'|'\''|':'|'\"'|'>'
    |'<'|'/'|'_'|';'|'('|')'
    |'&'|'!'|'#'|'%'|'*'|'+'|'['|']'|'{'|'}')* ;
```

But if there is a code like, `a="he is a good boy"` , it always gives an error on each space.

Comment: Do you have error with spaces in inverted commas (as written in your title) or with spaces in double quotes (as in your example `a="he is a good boy"`) ?

Comment: Yes, the error is in spaces in double quotes like the example (a="he is a good boy")